# How to get ONLY common rows of 2 tables on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Probably is something simple, but, let's say I have these:

```
Table User (id_user, name) 
Table A (id_a, name, type, #id_user)
```

And then I have another one that have only its own id and the other foreign keys

```
Table B (id_b, #id_user1, #id_user2, #id_a, #id_Something)
```

So, I need a query that returns ONLY the rows of table A and table B with what they have in common. I've tried `INNER JOIN` but it returns all rows of Table A where the id_user from there is equal to the id_user from table B. Like, if I have these:

Table User:

```
id_user   name
1         Hey
```

Table A:

```
id_a   name   type   id_user
1      a      car    1
2      b      cat    1
```

Table B:

```
id_b   id_user   id_user2         id_a   id_Something
1      1         Doesn't matter   1      Doesn't matter
```

I need to return only the common row between Table A and Table B (that'll be something like:

```
id_a   name   type   id_user   id_b   id_user2
1      a      car    1         1
```

I've tried `INNER JOIN` but it returns to me everything when the `id_user` from A =  `id_user` from B. I used this syntax:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       B 
INNER JOIN A ON A.id_user = B.id_user;
```

Hope I've made myself clear, thank you a lot.

Comment: No, you haven't made yourself clear.  For one thing, tables A and B don't even have the same structure, so how can they have a common row?

Comment: im sorry - not clear to me...

Comment: Which fields you want to show...

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you probably just want to add all the columns that you care about to your join on condition.  It would help if you had sample data and desired results that covered all of the cases you wanted to test for.  Since you're new, check [ask] for tips on asking good questions here.

Comment: Agree with @Kateract you should show end output what you want to get...

Comment: I also don't understand. What do you mean by "common rows" if you don't mean that the `id_user` matches?

Comment: Same here. What makes you decide for the car record and dismiss the cat record? Why is id_user2 empty in your results?

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're going after: "Show me all the rows in A and B which share the same id_user"

```
SELECT User.id_user, User.name, a.id_a, b.id_b
FROM User
INNER JOIN A ON a.id_user = User.id_user
INNER JOIN B on b.id_user = User.id_user
```